# Bootstrap popup window not working properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code. I'm trying to show up menu after clicking a button. Popup window shows but it is visible for only 1 second and invisible automatically. Please tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/npm.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: its working, you just included bootstrap.js files twice (one bootstrap.js and other bootstrap.min.js) For best practice,include js files just before closing your body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example. Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```